# How to write ROS package for gazebo

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-1.5, groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I designed my environment and robot in Gazebo environment but now I want to control it using ROS messages. How one can write code for that purpose using available ROS plugin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2208/how-to-write-ros-package-for-gazebo/) by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 131 on 2013-04-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

[this](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/ros_enabled_model_plugin) tutorial should help you. If you run into problems, just post them by updating your question.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-04-03**:
Thanks Andrei for your response. I am done with this tutorial but I still don't know that how to use ROS to set and get motion parameters for my gazebo model.

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-04-03**:
well, what exactly are you planning to achieve, maybe I can give you some directions

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-04-05**:
Thanks @Andrei. I designed my model in Gazebo 1.5. It can easily controllable from Gazebo GUI but I want to control it from ROS so that I can move and get feedback from ROS. For that purpose so far I accomplished to get ROS running plugin (according to tutorial) but I  want to know that what and where exactly I make changes to achieve it?